# Is there a way to save large panda data in multiple (parquet/csv) files as Pyspark does?

Tags: pandas, csv, parquet

I have large pandas dataframe and I need to save it to multiple (parquet/csv) files to reduce the volume space for the file.

I can divided it by divided the dataframe to multiple dataframe and save each one separately

Is there a method to do that directly?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such way in Pandas. IMHO, you can look [to_parquet](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Write-to-Parquet) from `Dask`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple function I often use:

```
def df_to_parquets(df, chunk_size=10):
    """
    Saves pandas dataframe to parquet in chunks
    """
    
    grp = df.groupby(df.index // chunk_size)
    for index, (name, group) in enumerate(grp):
        group.to_parquet(f'file_{index}.gzip', compression='gzip')
```

#### Sample Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 5), columns = ['col_'+str(x) for x in range(1, 6)])

df_to_parquets(df, chunk_size=2)
```

This would output 5 different parquet files.

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop be over range(chunk_size)?

Comment: @jjet why chunk size?

Comment: I was just trying out your function and it didn't quite work for me. Say your df has a million rows and you set chunk_size = 10000. Then, n_grp will be 100 but each grp.nth(i) will only have 100 rows. Replacing n_grp in the for loop with chunk_size solves that issue (though the interpretation of chunk_size isn't ideal)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer despite the error in the code: grouped.nth(i) does not get the i-th group but the i-th first elements of each group [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)=> the comment of @jjet. It works fine if you iterate through grp.groups and use counter to name your files.